# Using RdfProperty of array to custom class

Tags: c#, .net, rdf, rowlex, semweb

I have defined:

```
[RdfSerializable]
public class SomeItem
{
   // Unique identificator of the resource
   [ResourceUri]
   public string ID { get; set; }

   [RdfProperty( true )]
   public string SomeData { get; set; }
}

and in some other class: 

[RdfProperty(true)]
public SomeItem[] MyTestProp
{
   get
   {
      return new SomeItem[] { new SomeItem() { ID="1", SomeData="test1" }, new SomeItem() { ID="2", SomeData = "test2" } };
   }
}
```

When I try to serialize the class that contains this custom "MyTestProp" and it gave me that message:

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Am I wrong in defining those properties or there is a special way to define array to custom class? Note that serializing array to string for example is not crashing me that way, but it is working.

Whole source:

```
using System;
using NC3A.SI.Rowlex;

[assembly: Ontology("ROWLEXtest1", "http://www.test.com/MyOntology")]

namespace ROWLEXtest1
{
   [RdfSerializable( HasResourceUri=false )]
   public class Item
   {
      [RdfProperty(true)]
      public string MyProp;
   }

   [RdfSerializable]
   public class AllItems
   {
      [RdfProperty(true)] public string mTitle;

      private int id = new Random().Next(0, 20);

      [ResourceUri]
      public string ResourceUri 
      {
         get { return "This " + id.ToString(); }
      }

      [RdfProperty(false)]
      public Item[] Items;
   }

   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var item = new AllItems();
         item.mTitle = "Hello World!";
         item.Items = new Item[] { new Item(){ MyProp = "test1" }, new Item(){ MyProp = "test2" } };

         var doc = Rdfizer.Serialize(item);

         System.Console.Out.Write(doc.ToString());
      }
   }
}
```

Exception is:

> System.NullReferenceException was
>   unhandled   Message="Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object." 
>   Source="NC3A.SI.Rowlex"   StackTrace:
>          at NC3A.SI.Rowlex.RdfPropertyAttribute.ExtractRange(MemberInfo
>   memberInfo, Int32& minCardinality,
>   Int32& maxCardinality)
>          at NC3A.SI.Rowlex.RdfPropertyAttribute.ExtractRange(MemberInfo
>   memberInfo)
>          at NC3A.SI.Rowlex.Rdfizer.AppendProperty(RdfDocument
>   doc, MemberInfo memberInfo,
>   RdfPropertyAttribute attribute, Object
>   item, String resourceUri)
>          at NC3A.SI.Rowlex.Rdfizer.AppendSingleRdfSerializableObject(RdfDocument
>   doc, Object item)
>          at NC3A.SI.Rowlex.Rdfizer.ProcessItem(RdfDocument
>   doc, Object item, String[]
>   rangeTypeUris)
>          at NC3A.SI.Rowlex.Rdfizer.ExecuteSerialization(IEnumerable
>   objects)
>          at NC3A.SI.Rowlex.Rdfizer.Serialize(IEnumerable
>   objects, Boolean
>   tolerateUnserializebleObjects)
>          at NC3A.SI.Rowlex.Rdfizer.Serialize(Object
>   item)
>          at ROWLEXtest1.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) in
>   C:\ROWLEXtest1\ROWLEXtest1\Program.cs:line
>   40
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:

Comment: I have added full source plus exception information. I hope that will help you to examine the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did looks OK but there is one error: 
RdfProperty declaration should take "false" for MyTestProp as MyTestProp is not a data type property but object property (it returns objects and not literals).

However, I am not sure that this is the root of your problem. And even if it is, you should get [a decent error message with meaningful text instead of silly NullReferenceException](http://themonkeysgrinder.blogspot.com/2009/04/exceptional-apis.html). Therefore, I would like to try to reproduce your error and provide a fix if applicable. Could you please, specify

- the class and its decoration that hosts the MyTestProp,
- the code where you instantiate that class, and
- the code you use to for serialization.
- Had you apply assembly level attributes (for ontology - namespace mapping), please indicate that, too.

Maybe you could consider sending me your code sample to [admin at rowlex.net].

EDIT:
I could reproduce the exception, it is a bug in ROWLEX. **The fixed 2.0.1 version can now downloaded from the [ROWLEX](http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int) site.**